# Understanding the usage of executeAsyncScript in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to understand the documentation for Selenium's `executeAsyncScript` here (https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) , for instance in their first example they have :

```
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
       "window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 500);");
   System.out.println(
       "Elapsed time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

Now as far as I understand, the first argument is supposed to be a script, while the last one is a callback function, but in this example there is no callback, so what is going on here (arguments[] is empty right?).

If I wanted to have a function that returns a promise, and then print the promise, say `doSomething().then(function(result) { return result;)});` how would this work with the `executeAsyncScript` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the callback that the Selenium function provides you. Imagine that when you use **executeAsyncScript** that the script is wrapped in a Selenium function like this:

```
(function(args,,, callbackToServer){
    window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 500);
})(args,,, callbackToServer);
```

As you can see **arguments[arguments.length - 1]** actually references **callbackToServer** function.

For example your promise would look like this:

```
doSomething().then(function(result) { 
    arguments[arguments.length - 1](result);
)});
```

Comment: sorry but what Selenium function are you referring to?

Comment: See the example code. The first and third line are what the selenium function are accomplishing. The second line is what you injected.

Comment: Can you answer the second part of my question, I am horribly confused I'm afraid.

Comment: I updated your promise example. You will obviously have to keep track of the server callback. Perhaps set it to a variable.

Comment: So something like ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1]; doSomething().then(function(result){callback(result);}));");